# Given a vector of column names, how to check if all of them are numeric?

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a vector of column names from a data frame, how can I check if they’re all numeric. If there’s any non-numeric variable, how to identify it?

I’ve tried the first one but couldn’t move to the second one until I could solve it.

When I tried the following, I keep getting `false`

```
all(df[,numeric_cols] %>% is.numeric())
```

Is there a one line code that I can put within `if` condition, and find the one that is not numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if all class are numeric by

```
all(sapply(df[,numeric_cols], class) == "numeric")
```

To identify non-numeric columns one way would be :

```
names(Filter(function(x) !is.numeric(x), df[,numeric_cols]))
```